# Laravel Eloquent Update Error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update a row with eloquent in laravel 5.5 but i get this error.

**In Connection.php line 664:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1769888, `longitud` = -8,4700727 where `id` = '7'' at line 1 (SQL: update `centro` set `updated_at` = 2018-02-19 15:58:01, `latitud` = 43,1769888, `longitud` = -8,4700727 where `id` = 7)

**In PDOStatement.php line 107:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1769888, `longitud` = -8,4700727 where `id` = '7'' at line 1

**In PDOStatement.php line 105:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1769888, `longitud` = -8,4700727 where `id` = '7'' at line 1

Comment: Try showing us the code you attempted

Comment: my assumption without seeing the code would be: `43,1769888,` and `-8,4700727` the commas...

Comment: Please provide the full query and possibly the code executing the query not just the offending segment, thanks.